# Is there a shortcut to stop running in squish?

Tags: squish

When I run a test case using Squish (version 6.2.0), is there a way to stop the run from keyboard ?

I know that the Squish toolbar contains a button to do that. Unfortunately, this button is not accessible with the mouse when the test case is running (because the mouse is moved automatically by Squish).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With older Squish version like yours the brute force method is to close the application, or interfere with test script execution so that the application state is different than expected which will cause an object lookup to stall sooner or later, then you have time to use the mouse to operate the Squish control bar.

Another option is to use desktop automation software (AutoHotkey, AutoIt, AutoKey) to close the Squish control bar (regardless of the fact that it does not have the input focus), which will also abort the test script execution.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried Shift+F8?
The IDE lists this shortcut as "Cancels execution/recording of the test script".

You can find (and configure) the entire list of shortcuts under "Edit->Preferences->Global->Keys"

Comment: Unfortunately, this shortcut doesn't exist on my Squish version (which is 6.2.0). Hope it helps someone else !

Comment: @King'sjester: Ah, I run v6.4.1 - Also, the fact that you are not using the most recent version of Squish is *kinda* important information - if you do not state your version people may simply assume that you are keeping up to date... **Seriously, add that kind of info to your questions**

Comment: @laiwa-zhuang Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a minute to visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help); it should assist you in getting started here. Editing an answer is **not** the correct way to ask a follow-up question (nor would be editing  the question, or asking in comments). Please ask a **new question** with your follow-up question.